# how to update blueprint/ambari cluster in case increasing disks on worker machines

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, ambari

we have ambari cluster with 3 masters machines , two kafka's and 3 workers machines

each worker have 5 disks as :

```
/dev/sdb                   200G  477M   200G   3% /gr/sdb
/dev/sdc                   200G  183M   200G   1% /gr/sdc
/dev/sdd                   200G  283M   200G   2% /gr/sdd
/dev/sde                   200G   45M   200G   1% /gr/sde
```

we want to add additional 5 disks to each worker machine as ( /dev/sdf , /dev/sdh ..., etc )

**remark** - our Workers nodes runs both a DataNode and NodeManager

for now I understand that the following parameters should be update according to the new disks

```
dfs.datanode.data.dir ( from HDFS )

yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs ( from YARN )

yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs ( from YARN )
```

regarding that do we missed something else? that need to be configured?

**second**

after we reconfigured the parameters in ambari GUI ,

how to verify that ambari cluster recognize the new disks on worker machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to partition the disks, then mount them in the `/etc/fstab` to a directory.

Those settings look correct, though.

> how to verify that ambari cluster recognize the new disks on worker machines

It will alert if the configured volumes in the list of those properties are not mounted.

Comment: do you mean that we get alert from the ambari GUI? , second can you confirm that  the 3 parameters are the right parameters that need to reconfigure?

Comment: Ambari Alerts... The red number in the toolbar. And I did confirm